# Error on flutter create <>: The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected. It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

On creating a fresh Flutter project using the "flutter create <project_name>" command, I'm getting the following message(I'm using VS Code):

Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip'.
The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch:
Java home is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=/usr,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/xraydiffraction/.gradle/daemon,pid=7096,idleTimeout=null,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED,-Xmx1536M,-Dfile.encoding=utf8,-Duser.country=IN,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=b4bf4432-f4a0-47d3-8b18-d9b3e30e2601,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/xraydiffraction/.gradle/daemon,pid=7141,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED,-Xmx1536M,-Dfile.encoding=utf8,-Duser.country=IN,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]

I've tried upgrading Flutter but that didn't work.
What can I do to fix this?

Edit: I'm on MacOS. I'm adding flutter doctor -v log here. It's all normal.
% flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.3, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale
en-IN)
• Flutter version 3.13.3 on channel stable at
/Users/xraydiffraction/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 2524052335 (7 days ago), 2023-09-06 14:32:31 -0700
• Engine revision b8d35810e9
• Dart version 3.1.1
• DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/xraydiffraction/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
• ANDROID_HOME = /Users/xraydiffraction/Library/Android/sdk
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14E300c
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.1)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.72.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.2.1 22D68
darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 116.0.5845.187

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

Comment: hi can you share the log from `flutter doctor -v` and which OS are you on?

Comment: I just added that to the question.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct version of Java installed. Flutter typically requires Java 8 or later. You can check your Java version by running `java -version` in your terminal.

Comment: This is the java -version output:
openjdk version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.8+7 (build 17.0.8+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.8+7 (build 17.0.8+7, mixed mode)

Comment: It's been working well till today. I don't know what changed.

Comment: try restarting your mac then lol

Comment: I did that, didn't work

Comment: just to be clear, does this error message come when you run that flutter project for android? or while creating a new flutter project that error is thrown?

Comment: It shows in the errors when I create a new project.

Comment: this looks like a gradle issue, I have had this issue in the past while creating Android builds, but not when creating a new project. so does it create a new Flutter project or not?

Comment: don't use Java version 17. use lower, like Java 11